# CSS-transition on elements added dynamically via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I create an element with like this:

```
var dynamic_gallery = document.createElement("li");
```

Now I assign a class to it, which gives the element style `a { height:0;transition-duration:.4s; }`

```
dynamic_gallery.className = "gallery-container";
```

Right after this step, I add another class with style `{ height:400px !important; }`

```
dynamic_gallery.className += " gallery-exp";
```

From my understanding, the element should be created invisible and immediately recieve a change in height and grow smoothly to 400px.
So why will it still appear instantly in full height?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CSS3 transition-delay event will be fired for elements after being live.
Here you have set height to 0 but still "li" element is not in DOM(so its not live).

so after assigining height to 0px make it live.
ie

```
document.body.appendChild(dynamic_gallery)
```

The "li" is live now,and transition-duration:.4s event has been registered.

Now increase the height to 400px by assigning the class,
    dynamic_gallery.className += " gallery-exp";

You will see smooth animation.

EDIT:Most browser needs time to make element live so we need a timeout of 0 seconds to make it work.

hence it should be

```
setTimeout(function(){
    dyna_gallery.className += " gallery-exp";},0)
```

instead of

```
dyna_gallery.className += " gallery-exp";
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zYLmw/

Comment: This does not work for me, see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HZ6VP/)

Comment: i have updated answer please check the fiddle.

Comment: seems that this is not working in FF (V. 72) anymore :(
i just got good result, that the animation is properly starting, with a delay of 20ms.

Answer (score 3):

Why would it grow "smoothly" ?

All changes of the DOM (including CSS) you do in your script aren't rendered until your code ends.

If you want the change to be visible, you have to force your code to end, for example with a `setTimeout` :

```
var dynamic_gallery = document.createElement("li");
dynamic_gallery.className = "gallery-container"; 
... appending
setTimeout(function(){
    dynamic_gallery.className += " gallery-exp";
}, 2000); // wait 2 seconds before adding the class
```

But :

- this won't make it smooth at all. To do this you would have to call many changes (changing the height of the elements rather than a class) instead of just one
- using `!important` is almost always the mark of a bad design. Here it is.

Here's an example of animating the height of your element from `0` to `400` px :

```
(function grow(){
  var h = (parseInt(dynamic_gallery.style.height)||0)+1;
  dynamic_gallery.style.height = h+'px';
  if (h<400) setTimeout(grow, 30);
})();
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/gupup/2/edit)

Comment: Well thank you, I did not know that the code will be completely executed before rendering, I am still learning.
But how can I achieve that kind of effect then?

Comment: @MoritzFriedrich I added the code to do the animation in vanilla js